# Text in center of chartJS lead to infiniteloop

Tags: html, css, chart.js

I've tried

```
<div class="col-2 text-center">
    <canvas id="htmlChart"></canvas>
    <div class="chart-inner"><h5>34</h5></div>
</div>
<div class="col-2 text-center">
    <canvas id="cssChart"></canvas>
    <div class="chart-inner"><h5>34</h5></div>
</div>
<div class="col-2 text-center">
    <canvas id="jsChart"></canvas>
    <div class="chart-inner"><h5>34</h5></div>
</div>
<div class="col-2 text-center">
    <canvas id="jqueryChart"></canvas>
    <div class="chart-inner"><h5>34</h5></div>
</div>
<div class="col-2 text-center">
    <canvas id="reactChart"></canvas>
    <div class="chart-inner"><h5>34</h5></div>
</div>
<div class="col-2 text-center">
    <canvas id="nodeChart"></canvas>
    <div class="chart-inner"><h5>34</h5></div>
</div>
```

with these CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .chart-inner {
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
    .chart-inner h5 {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-top: 27px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

I kept getting *infinite loop*

[image]

https://tmcabe.herokuapp.com/

I was expecting to get

[image]

Any hints ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I never worked with `chart.js` so if i make mistakes don't hold them against me, And its almost 5AM so i'm a bit dizzy if something isn't clear pleas do fix it.

Now the issue seems to have something to do with how `chart.js` handles responsiveness and because you have `responsive: true` read this

**The responsive option:**

> Resizes the chart canvas when its container does (important note...).

**The Important Note**

> Detecting when the canvas size changes can not be done directly from the canvas element. Chart.js uses its parent container to update the canvas render and display sizes. However, this method requires the container to be relatively positioned and dedicated to the chart canvas only. Responsiveness can then be achieved by setting relative values for the container size [example](https://codepen.io/Zohir/pen/ZEENJob)

---

From that we understand that we need a relatively positioned element specifically for the canvas to live in and we also need to set a height and width for that parent (these values will be treated as a starting point and a max height/width for the canvas)

## What's causing the loop ?

So we know that the canvas need it's own parent element that is relatively positioned and a set height/width.

```
<div class="col-2 text-center">
    <canvas id="nodeChart"></canvas>
    <div class="chart-inner"><h5>34</h5></div>
</div>
```

That's the code you have, Thanks to bootstrap's class `col-2` we have a position relative on the parent of the canvas, this would've been fine if the parent wasn't shared between the canvas and `chart-inner`

**Why?**

And i'm just guessing here i didn't dig into the source code

`chart.js` uses a a mask of the canvas's dimensions which is an absolutely positioned `iframe` places it next to the canvas makes it fill the parent now the iframes will match the parent dimensions (parent, child relationship with position relative and absolute), then it copies the height of the iframe to the canvas now the canvas matches the parents height which is the original height of the canvas + `div.chart-inner` which means iframe is always larger than the canvas, and because the parent has been resized the whole process will keep happening.

**Note:* i noticed that a border on the canvas can cause the loop also, can be fixed with `box-sizing: border-box;`

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p91wh6ad/) recreating the issue**

---

**Solution**

Simple all you have to do is give the canvas it's own parent

1. rethink your structure
2. wrap the canvas with an empty div
3. make `div.chart-inner` absolute which would be helpful to center the text [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cw3d2ynh/1/)

I can't recommend one way over the other because i never worked with `chart.js` before

Also i couldn't do anything about centering the text because fixing the loop requires changing the whole structure, and because the site your provided is laggy i couldn't copy the styles, Howver

If anything isn't clear please don't hesitate

Comment: Thank-you very much for your help, will try that and update you the result.